# Discord v13 bot can't seem to identify what is a text channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So when I am trying to set a verify channel with my bot. It doesn't seem to be able to find identify the text channel

Code:

```
const db = require('quick.db');
const { PREFIX } = require('../../config');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'setverification',
        aliases: ['sv', 'setv', 'setverify'],
        category: 'moderation',
        description: 'Sets Verification Channel And Role',
        usage: '[channel name | channel ID | channel mention] <role name | role ID | role mention]',
        accessableby: 'Administrators'
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        let prefix;
        let fetched = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`);

        if (fetched === null) {
            prefix = PREFIX
        } else {
            prefix = fetched
        }

        if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("**You Do Not Have Required Permissions! - [ADMINISTRATOR]!**");

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Channel Name Where The User Should Be Asked To Verify!**");

        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Role Which Will Be Added After The User Is Verified!**");

        let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase());
        if (!channel || channel.type !== "GUILD_TEXT") return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Valid Channel!**")

        let role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1]) || message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase() === args[1].toLocaleLowerCase());
        if (!role) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Valid Role!**");

        let verifiedchannel = channel;

        try {
            let a = await db.fetch(`verificationchannel_${message.guild.id}`);
            let b = await db.fetch(`verificationrole_${message.guild.id}`);

            if (channel.id === a && role.id === b) {
                return message.channel.send('**This Channel is Already Set As Verification Channel!**');
            } else if (channel.id === a && role.id === b) {
                return message.channel.send("**This Role is Already Set As Verification Role!**");
            }
            else {
                message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
                    if (channel.type === 'category' && channel.id === verifiedchannel.id) return;
                    let r = channel.permissionOverwrites.get(role.id);
                    if (!r) return;
                    if (r.deny.has("VIEW_CHANNEL") || r.deny.has("SEND_MESSAGES")) return;

                    channel.createOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
                        VIEW_CHANNEL: false
                    });

                    channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
                        SEND_MESSAGES: true
                    });
                });

                verifiedchannel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                    VIEW_CHANNEL: false
                });
                bot.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).channels.cache.get(channel.id).send(`**Welcome To ${message.guild.name}!\nTo Get Verified Type - \`${prefix}verify\`**`);
                db.set(`verificationchannel_${message.guild.id}`, channel.id);
                db.set(`verificationrole_${message.guild.id}`, role.id);

                return message.channel.send(`**Verification Channel And Role Has Been Set Successfully in \`${channel.name}\`!**`);
            };
        } catch {
            return message.channel.send("**Error - `Missing Permissions Or Channel Is Not A Text Channel!`**");
        };
    }
};
```

It is able to know what channel it is sent and know the role (Bot's permissions are set to  Administrator). I think it a deprecation problem. This code was made with v12

Code example:

[image: Discord code example]

Comment: You only put that in the `catch` block so another error may be happening - try changing it to `catch(err) {console.log(err}` (instead of `catch {...}`)and tell us what it logs

Comment: This could be anything, you are catching the error but never used the error parameter that is thrown. `try { } catch(error) { console.log(error); }`

Comment: I got `TypeError: channel.permissionOverwrites.get is not a function` I can't seem to find the documentation for it. What changed from v12 to v13?

Comment: Try doing `channel.permissionOverwrites.resolve` instead

Comment: Getting a new error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')` Seems like it's not resolve

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `await message.guild.channels.fetch()` instead of `message.guild.channels.cache`. It seems the issue you are having is that `channel.permissionOverwrites` is `undefined`. It's possible that the channel cache does not cache permission overwrites. You also need to take into account the various properties and methods used in your code that are different in djs v13. These include MrMythical's answer, the new `channel.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY"` instead of `"category"`, and `channel.createOverwrite()` and `channel.updateOverwrite()` no longer existing.

Comment: Still no chance. And I found out the category thing yesterday but forgot to tell in here

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildChannel#permissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites) has changed. It used to return a `Collection`, but now it returns a [`PermissionOverwriteManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager). Use `.resolve` on it instead:

```js
let r = channel.permissionOverwrites.resolve(role.id)
```

Comment: Refer from the comment:

Getting a new error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve') Seems like it's not resolve

Comment: What does `channel` log then?

Comment: My console.log doesn't seem to work. It seems to be ignored

Comment: wait you said this was written in v12? V12 is going to be broken soon, or it might be now. You should update

Comment: It seems they are using v13, I think they mean that the code they are using was originally created to work with v12.

Comment: The code was made in v12 and I am using v13